Custom video splash screen not displaying, default Android splash screen appears instead
I am trying to create a custom splash screen in my Flutter app using a video. However, the default Android splash screen with the app logo displays for 10 seconds before my video splash screen appears for just 1-2 seconds.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I created a SplashPage with a video splash screen using VideoPlayerController.asset.
I modified styles.xml and launch_background.xml to disable the default Android splash screen.
I configured navigation to the main page (MainPage) after the video finishes playing.
Here’s my Flutter code:


    import 'dart:async';  
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
    import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';  
    import 'package:armasedu/app/pages/main_page/main_page.dart';  

    class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {  
      static const String pageName = '/splash';  

      @override  
      _SplashPageState createState() => _SplashPageState();  
    }  

    class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {  
      late VideoPlayerController _controller;  

      @override  
      void initState() {  
        super.initState();  
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/image/png/splash.mp4')  
          ..initialize().then((_) {  
            setState(() {});  
            _controller.play();  
            _controller.setLooping(false);  
            // Navigate to MainPage after the video finishes (10 seconds)  
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {  
              Navigator.pushReplacement(  
                context,  
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()),  
              );  
            });  
          });  
      }  

      @override  
      void dispose() {  
        super.dispose();  
        _controller.dispose();  
      }  

      @override  
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
        return Scaffold(  
          body: Center(  
            child: _controller.value.isInitialized  
                ? AspectRatio(  
                    aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,  
                    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),  
                  )  
                : CircularProgressIndicator(), // Show loading indicator while the video loads  
          ),  
        );  
      }  
    }



AndroidManifest.xml
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:name="${applicationName}"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    <meta-data
      android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
      android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>

styles.xml
   <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>

launch_background.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</layer-list>


We have to do some changes to resolve this issue ,
1.You can try to disable android native splash screen completely
Modify the styles.xml and launch_background.xml files to make the Android native splash screen as minimal as possible.
style.xml
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
</style>

launch_background.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</layer-list>

2.Ensure the Flutter Load fastly,

Optimize Flutter App Startup

Use the flutter build apk --release to build a release version.
Minimize any heavy initialization in the main() method.

Pre-cache the Video Asset Add the video to your Flutter app's assets
and pre-cache it in pubspec.yaml:



flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/image/png/splash.mp4


3.Make Flutter to Load fast,
Flutter may not initialize the custom SplashPage until its framework is ready. Use the WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() method to minimize delays:
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

you can get more details about the WidgetFlutterBindin.ensureInitialized method referring this article
4.Handle video splash screen repo,
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        _controller.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              )
            : Container(color: Colors.black),
        if (!_controller.value.isInitialized)
          Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()), // Fallback while loading
      ],
    ),
  );
}

you can refer this it will solve how to make splash screen quickly
5.Remove native splash screen duration.
If the default splash screen still lingers, reduce its display time in the Android MainActivity by overriding the onCreate method:
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // This ensures Flutter's first frame is prioritized
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
}

6.Check the flutter dependencies versions
flutter upgrade
flutter pub upgrade

Those steps will help to you resolve your issue , if it will not solve your issue comment the status of you issue and then we will try to another option for resolve your issue.
